# EOL in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Why in regex library in Java the EOL is found in the next command

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( "[\\\\r\\\\n$]+" ).matcher( " where " );
if ( matcher.find() )
{
// found reaction
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a new line regex. You're literally matching one of the following characters 1 or more times: `\`, `r`, `\`, `n` or `$`. In `where`, there is an `r`, so the pattern is found in the string.

The new line regex is `\r|\n|\r\n`. In JAVA, you need to escape backslashes, so it will be `\\r|\\n|\\r\\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. The regex is not correct, you only need one escape sequence. The pattens are `\r` and `\n`, not `\\r` and `\\n`. In Java you need to escape them once, so the patterns are `\\r` and `\\n`.
2. The string you are searching in ( `" where "`) doesn't contain any carriage return + line feed (just the \r).

This will find a carriage return + line feed:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( "[\\r\\n$]+" ).matcher( " where \n" );
if ( matcher.find() ){
    System.out.println("found");
}
```